# Magento2: How to get customer zip code based on the customer location (Guest Users)

Tags: magento2, customer, geoip

I would like to get the customer zip code based on the customer location (Guest Users)

Please let me know if anyone has an idea how to get it done.

Thank You

Comment: @Suesh I would suggest to try with geo ip modules.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to work something like this but this code is not tested lets try it

// get-location.js

```
// Function to get the user's location
function getUserLocation() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            // Send the location data to your server
            sendLocationToServer(latitude, longitude);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("Error getting location: " + error.message);
        });
    } else {
        console.error("Geolocation is not available in this browser");
    }
}

// Function to send location data to the server via AJAX
function sendLocationToServer(latitude, longitude) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/your-custom-endpoint-url", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log("Location data sent successfully");
            } else {
                console.error("Failed to send location data: " + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

now your endpoint

// Create a custom controller file in your Magento module
// app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Controller/GuestLocation/Index.php

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Controller\GuestLocation;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
        $locationData = json_decode($data, true);

        // Process the location data as needed (e.g., store it in a database)

        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        return $result->setData(['message' => 'Location data received']);
    }
}
```